# Integrating stripe with bigcommerce

Tags: stripe-payments, bigcommerce

I'm integrating stripe payment gateway in bigcommerce.
when I go to the integration page, it asks me for bank account details. I have tried to fill out this form with test account numbers but it shows the error of "can not use known test account numbers in live mode." and I don't know how to enable the test mode.

I have googled this issue but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your test mode is enabled. Go to your admin panel > payments > Enable Test Mode. Hope that helps.